# SameTime 9 - Chat history deletion

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-sametime

How do I delete individual ST chat history in SameTime 9 (embedded)?

For Lotus Notes 8.53, I could do it just by selecting a specific chat of a specific person, and just press Delete. It would get deleted.

So what is the similar action for SameTime 9?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Lotus Notes Chat Preferences]

I think it depends on what you have selected in your Chat History preferences.

If you use the "Save to mail file" option, then you can view your chat history in Notes, and delete the individual chats.

If you use the "Location:" option, then you need to open the directory specified in the edit box.  Each chat is a separate file that can be deleted using Windows Explorer.